# Firebase functions setting value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How would one set a value in the Firebase Database from Firebase functions. Like just change or add a value? I don't want it to do it when something happens in the database, just wondering how you would do it manually.

Comment: Are you referring to Firebase [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests? Can you provide a bit more of a concrete example and did you go through the getting started guide as that covers writing data

Comment: Yes referring to cloud functions. Literally just trying to update a value in the database through a function. Yes went through the getting started guide.

Comment: Since you went through the getting started guide which shows how to craft a function that [writes data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) (which sounds like what you are asking), can you elaborate on what code you're having difficulty with? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the code that's not working?

Comment: I don't have any code for what I'm trying to do. I don't have code that doesn't work, I just need an example of how to update values in my database in Firebase Functions in Typescript. I don't have the code for it currently.

Comment: There are lots of code samples, videos, and blogs that cover basic use of Cloud Functions.  I suggest starting with the documentation, then doing some searches to get acquainted with Cloud Functions.

Comment: Haven't found any. Would be great if you could provide some.

Comment: That's not really how SO works. You should attempt some code and when you get stuck, post it and we will take a look. There are some pretty specific typescript code samples in the getting started guide [Use TypeScript for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript). In fact there's a [specific example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#how_promises_work_with_functions) that shows how to change an a value of 'hello' to 'world' and write it out. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh, and check out this [massive array of code samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) as well

Comment: @jay, the 'specific example' link is good, except its updating the value when something happens in the database. I just want to update it when I run a function, not on 'Write' or any other event. Do you understand?

Comment: Not really. Whether you trigger a function or some other task triggers a function, the function is still triggered either way. Again, in the documentation there's an exports.addMessage function that takes a message and stores it in the database. It can be called with `https://us-central1-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage?text=uppercaseme`. So that will update a node in the database when you call the function, which is what you asked. It's all in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-and-execute-addmessage)

Comment: Nevermind, just figured it out, might just go ahead and answer my Own question.